# Modify environment with tests while running Postman Newman in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, testing, postman, puppeteer, newman

I'm running Newman in a Node Script. The collection has environment variables such as `{{claimNum}}` that would increment with each post by the test.

**Example**:

I have this **collection** request body

```
 <ClaimIdentification>
      <company>0001</company>
      <office>100</office>
      <claimNum>{{claimNum}}</claimNum>
 </ClaimIdentification>
```

And in the **global environment** JSON:

```
  {
  "enabled": true,
  "key": "claimNum",
  "value": "15200",
  "type": "text"
},
```

And the collection has this **test**:

```
pm.globals.set("claimNum", + pm.globals.get("claimNum") + 1);
```

But when ran in the script, the global.json file won't be modified and the "value" would stay the same. When this same parameters are run in the desktop app, it works.

Is there a solutions for this, should this work?

**UPDATE1:**

This is the newman script:

```
  collection: require('${__dirname}/ThirdServiceInjured.json'),
  reporters: 'json',
  globals: require('${__dirname}/globals.json')

}).on('done', function (err, summary) {
  if (err || summary.error) {
      console.error('>>> ERROR - Collection run failed.');
  }
  else {
    console.log(success('Collection run completed:'));  
    console.log(summary.run.executions[0].response.text());
  }
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Using this script and still not writing over the enviroment:

```
const newman = require('newman'); // require newman in your project
const fs = require('fs');
const envName = '${__dirname}/environment_qbe600.json';
const env = require('${__dirname}/environment_qbe600.json');

newman.run({
  collection: require('${__dirname}/ThirdServiceInjured.json'),
  reporters: 'cli',
  environment: envName,
  iterationCount: 3

}).on('done', function (err, summary) {
  if (err || summary.error) {
      console.error('>>> ERROR - Collection run could failed.');
}
else {
  const newmanValue = summary.environment.values.members[0].value;
  env.values[0].value = newmanValue;
  console.log(summary.run.executions[0].response.text());
  fs.writeFile(envName, JSON.stringify(env, null, 2), function (err) {
    if (err) return
  })
}
});
```

**UPDATE 3:**

This is the enviroment:

```
{
  "id": "ecabb925-829e-69f8-2348-f71dc76c0e87",
  "name": "Test",
  "values": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "host",
      "value": "${___server}",
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "company",
      "value": "0001",
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "claimNbr",
      "value": "14600",
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "dni",
      "value": "150",
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "cost",
      "value": "107000",
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "testNum",
      "value": "157",
      "type": "text"
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": 1515789551332,
  "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
  "_postman_exported_at": "2018-01-12T20:39:14.795Z",
  "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/5.5.0"
```

And the test section from the collection:

```
"event": [
    {
        "listen": "test",
        "script": {
            "type": "text/javascript",
            "exec": [
                "pm.environment.set(\"claimNbr\", +pm.environment.get(\"claimNbr\") + 1);",
                "pm.environment.set(\"testNum\", +pm.environment.get(\"testNum\") + 1);",
                "pm.environment.set(\"dni\", +pm.environment.get(\"dni\") + 1);",
                "pm.environment.set(\"cost\", +pm.environment.get(\"cost\") + 1000);"
            ]
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: Is that valid syntax for the variable? Would `pm.globals.set("claimNbr", pm.globals.get("claimNbr") + 1)` not be what you need?

Comment: Mine is the syntax from the JSON when exported. But yes, on the desktop app is: `pm.globals.set("claimNum", +pm.globals.get("claimNum") + 1);`

Comment: Are you able to update the question with your node script using Newman please?

Comment: @DannyDainton done, sorry for the delay!

Comment: Thank you. I added an answer with something basic that worked for me.

Comment: Re-reading your question again - when you run the test using those files, the globals.json file won’t change or be updated. It’s a static file so it will always be a specific value, the test would just work from that value each time and increase the number of the variable, only during the execution of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the following recent issue on the [Postman Github account](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/1176)

If you change the `global` variable to be a `environment` variable that would allow you to see the updated value each time it's run. I just changed your `test` code to `environment` rather than `global`.

```
pm.environment.set("claimNum", + pm.environment.get("claimNum") + 1)
```

I created a basic node script to run Newman with the Collection and Environment files exported from Postman:

```
var newman = require('newman')

newman.run({
    collection: `${__dirname}/default_collection.json`,
    environment: `${__dirname}/default_environment.json`,
    reporters: 'cli',
    iterationCount: 10
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) { throw err }
  })
```

My two files referenced in the newman script:

**default_collection.json**

```
{
    "info": {
        "name": "Test_Collection",
        "_postman_id": "d08f1b36-591a-f25f-aaaa-4368ca966fb4",
        "description": "",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Test_Request",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "id": "068b6634-e310-46e9-86fc-265376c65ff6",
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "exec": [
                            "console.log(pm.environment.get('claimNum'))"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "{\n\t\"id\": {{claimNum}}\n}"
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "localhost:3000/test",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "3000",
                    "path": [
                        "test"
                    ]
                },
                "description": ""
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "prerequest",
            "script": {
                "id": "4c1d562f-e4d5-4017-8f25-48ac0b6aa3fc",
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "id": "026c029e-a427-4624-b196-3d8982a103f1",
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    "pm.environment.set(\"claimNum\", + pm.environment.get(\"claimNum\") + 1)"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**default_environment.json**

```
{
  "id": "539073e6-adab-f812-95b0-82d4d82ce4b2",
  "name": "test_environment",
  "values": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "claimNum",
      "value": "9",
      "type": "text"
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": 1515782483636,
  "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
  "_postman_exported_at": "2018-01-12T18:42:04.661Z",
  "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/5.5.0"
}
```

I added `iterationCount: 10` to the script so that I could see the `claimNum` increase on each iteration.

[image: Newman Test Run]

In Postman, I added a simple `console.log()` to write out the `claimNum` on each test run - You can see the output in the image above.

```
console.log(pm.environment.get('claimNum'))
```

My request body in using `JSON` but the `{{claimNum}}` would work the same with `XML` like in your example.

This one solution to the problem but as it's using not using a `global` variable and I'm unsure of your requirement - It might not be what you're after.

---

**UPDATE 1**

Depending on the use case that you have - The environment file can be updated to show the last run value and can use this value in the next request - So that it's not repeatedly running a test against the same value in the static file. Running the following code would run the test and then update the value in the `default_environment.json` file.

```
const newman   = require('newman')
const fs       = require('fs');
const fileName = `${__dirname}/default_environment.json`;
const file     = require(fileName);

newman.run({
    collection: `${__dirname}/default_collection.json`,
    environment: `${__dirname}/default_environment.json`,
    reporters: 'cli',
    iterationCount: 3
}).on('done', function (err, summary) {
  if (err || summary.error) {
    console.error('>>> ERROR - Collection run failed.');
  }
  else {
    const newmanValue = summary.environment.values.members[0].value
    file.values[0].value = newmanValue

    fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(file, null, 2), function (err) {
      if (err) return
    })
  }
})
```

My `environment` file would look something like this following the test run:

```
{
  "name": "test_environment",
  "values": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "claimNum",
      "value": 19,
      "type": "text"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: File Update]

---

**UPDATE 2**

Having modified the code again with the new information this is working locally for me:

*Newman Run Script*

```
const newman  = require('newman')
const fs      = require('fs')
const envName = `${__dirname}/default_environment.json`
const env     = require(envName)

newman.run({
  collection: require(`${__dirname}/default_collection.json`),
  reporters: 'cli',
  environment: envName,
  iterationCount: 3

}).on('done', function (err, summary) {
  if (err || summary.error) {
      console.error('ERROR - Collection run could failed')
}
else {
  const claimNbr  = summary.environment.values.members[0].value
  const testNum   = summary.environment.values.members[1].value
  const dni       = summary.environment.values.members[2].value
  const cost      = summary.environment.values.members[3].value

  env.values[0].value = claimNbr
  env.values[1].value = testNum
  env.values[2].value = dni
  env.values[3].value = cost

  fs.writeFile(envName, JSON.stringify(env, null, 2), function (err) {
    if (err) return
  })
  console.log('Collection run complete') 
}
})
```

*The test section in the Collection file*

```
    "name": "Test_Request",
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "id": "a407e1e2-4961-4c65-af1b-22190b1ab0cc",
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    "pm.environment.set(\"claimNbr\", + pm.environment.get(\"claimNbr\") + 1)",
                    "pm.environment.set(\"testNum\", + pm.environment.get(\"testNum\") + 1)",
                    "pm.environment.set(\"dni\", + pm.environment.get(\"dni\") + 1)",
                    "pm.environment.set(\"cost\", + pm.environment.get(\"cost\") + 1000)",
                    "",
                    "console.log(JSON.stringify(pm.response.json()))"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

*Postman Request Body*

[image: Postman Request Body]

*Script Running and Updating the environment file*

[image: Newman Run]

Comment: I'm sorry, how can I call the `--export-enviroment` in the script?

Comment: I’m not sure that you would need too. Those flags are only useful if you’re running this from the command line, you’re running it from a node script. In your script you have `globals:` change that for `environment:` and also add an environment.json file where your global.json file. Ensure that you do the same for your test too.

Comment: Check your syntax in the test it should read `pm.environment` and not `pm.globals`

Comment: Adding an update to change the value in the environment file after each run.

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I followed the instructions but the enviroment is still not being written (I'm not using globals anymore). Also the body response is the only useful thing I need, is there any way to log it better than:
 `console.log(summary.run.executions[0].response.text());` 
?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do -  Try adding `console.log(pm.response.text())` or use `.json()` to the `Tests` tab of the request in the collection. That would show the response body for each request in the console. I'm not sure that information is contained in the newman summary object.

Comment: In your recent update you need to ensure that the `env` , `envName` and `collection:` strings are all using backticks  ( ` ) rather than single quotes ( ' ) apart from that, I ran it locally and it worked.

Comment: Just to confirm, Have you changed the test syntax in the request to be `pm.environment.set` rather than `pm.globals.set`?

Comment: Yes Danny, I changed the syntax in everything, even using the backticks and still no luck. I'll update with the enviroment and tests from the collection.

Comment: Added a final update - The code to get and update the values is horrible but it will work and would need to be refactored. If this doesn't work for you, i'm out of ideas.

Comment: Works wonders, thanks a lot! I had to re-arrange the enviroments in order for some values to work, but now it's perfect. Thanks for the patience and godspeed

Comment: Yay! Ah yeah, you have the `host` value too so the numbers would need to be moved down. It was an ordeal but I learnt a lot too. Glad it's doing what you want or at least something that you can work with. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this option :

```
--export-globals <path>
```

When calling newman add this option to have your `globals.json` to be updated.

Comment: Depending on the newman implementation being used - The `--export-globals` flag *might* not work as this is only used on the CLI. This is the link to the [Newman API](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#api-reference) where you may need to use either the `options` or `summary` object in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Although the [Newman API Ref](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#api-reference) doesn't mention it, the `options` object you pass to `newman.run` *does* have support for writing out both global and environment vars in the same manner as the `newman` cli. The tip was found in the [newman issues list](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/831#issuecomment-367339649).

```
newman.run({
    collection: '/path/to/collection.json',
    environment: require('/path/to/env'),
    exportEnvironment: '/path/to/env.json',
    globals: require('/path/to/global'),
    exportGlobals: '/path/to/global.json'
})
    .on('done', (err, summary) => {
        console.log(summary.environment.values);
    })
```

Also Note, for some weird reason other event listeners like: `.on('beforeItem',() => {})` and `.on('item',() => {})` don't have the property `summary.environment`

Comment: Is this something you've tried (late to the party, not sure if you are still active sansSpoon) or is it documentation knowledge only?